# Understanding Secondary Log Hard Disk Impact on Write Speed and Data Integrity After Power Outage

Tags: database-design, hardware, ssd

I've recently come across the notion that a secondary log hard disk can be employed to enhance write operation speed in a database system. I find this concept intriguing but am struggling to grasp the mechanics behind it. Could someone shed light on why a secondary log hard disk is effective in accelerating write operations?

Moreover, I've stumbled upon the statement that both SSDs and HDDs can retain all data written, even after a power outage. This caught my attention, and I'm curious to understand the mechanisms that allow both storage types to maintain data integrity post-power outage. If anyone could provide insights into this aspect as well, it would greatly contribute to my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

On all storage media (even SDRAM) random writes sprayed all over a big file are much slower than the same number of bytes written in a sequential chunk. For random writes, harddisks have to physically move the head between each write. SSDs have to erase full sectors, that may be much larger than the data being written which means the data that isn't overwritten has to be copied in order to not be erased. Even SDRAM has to open a row in order to access it, which takes time.

This means in order to be fast, a database to reduce the number of random writes as much as possible. A common scenario is that you have a large amount of data that doesn't fit in RAM, but a smaller working set that does and is being updated perhaps frequently. For example this corresponds to data belonging to users who are online.

Therefore the database will update data in RAM and write it to disk not too often, trying to coalesce adjacent bits into larger chunks. That way if a row is updated several times, it is only written once.

However if power is lost or there is a crash, data in RAM is lost. In order to ensure durability, the database actually writes everything twice. There are various ways this is done, but it usually involves a log. As the database updates a row in RAM, it writes information about what it's about to do into the log file. For example, it can write the new row into the log file.

The whole point of this is that the log file is written sequentially, without any random access. Everything is simply appended at the end. Therefore, writing is very fast. Even more important, when you COMMIT and the database must make sure everything is actually written to disk, it only has to wait for that sequential write to finish, which takes a lot less time than doing lots of random writes to update every row in the huge table files.

Crash recovery involves reading the log (sequential, fast) and applying the modifications described in it to the tables. The log contains information about transactions, so that in case of recovery, only complete committed transactions will be executed.

Anyway, so in normal operations you'll have writes to your tables, which may be sequential if you update large chunks or import tables... or random if your application does lots of small inserts and updates. At the same time you have sequential writes to the log. If you put data and log on separate disks, then these two write streams can happen at the same time, which is faster than one disk doing all the work. With spinning harddisks it is quite noticeable. Of course SSDs are much faster, so it is less noticeable.

For the same reason, the more disks the faster it runs, **if** your data is spread among the disks and your workload hits data on all the disks so they can work in parallel.

Answer (score -1):

The basic principle is always that more disks means more performance of the storage subsystem, because physically a disk can only be read or written from one place at a time (wherever the head and arm are positioned).

The physical repositioning of the read/write head is the slowest operation of the individual disk.

Multiple disks can read/write from multiple places at a time, and therefore if data is spread around over different disks, the more chance that any two requests can be dished out to different disks, rather than one request having to wait queued whilst another executes.

As for disks retaining all data after power failure, that is frankly the whole point of disk storage: to be durable even if power is lost.

Once data is fully written to disk, then losing power or unplugging the disk drive will not cause any change in the stored data or its readability.

This is different from ordinary computer RAM, which loses all data as soon as the machine is switched off.